# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'item_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `order_service

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

This is my first time I make a system with an order...
I am confusing how can I insert data to the pivot table order_services

**Tables:**

order table: (id, total)

services table: (id, name, price)

item table:(id, name)

order_service table: (order_id,service_id, item_id, quantity, amount)

**Models:**

**Order.php**

```
protected $guarded = [];
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class)->withPivot('order_id','service_id','item_id','quantity','amount');
  (Service::class,'order_service','order_id','service_id','item_id','quantity','amount');
}
```

**Service.php:**

```
  protected $guarded = [];

public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('order_id','service_id','item_id','quantity','amount');

  (Order::class,'order_service','order_id','service_id','item_id','quantity','amount');
}
```

**OrderService.php:**

```
protected $guarded = [];

    protected $table = 'order_service';
```

**OrderController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $data = request()->validate([
            'total' => 'required',
           ]);

       $order= Order::create($data);
           if ($request->serviceOrders) {
            foreach ($request->serviceOrders as $service) {

                $order->services()->attach($service);
```

**Output:**

> Error Function name must be a string

Comment: You are not giving the pivot table info (item_id) when you're ataching. `$order->services()->attach($service);` only fills `order_id` and `service_id`. where is it supposed to get the `item_id` from ?

Comment: @N69S thank you for answering me but how can I do that? should I change the relationship or somthing like that?

Comment: the question is "what value is supposed to go in there ?" and only you can get the answer.

Comment: @N69S I just changed the relationship and it worked ! thank you very much for explanation